# How to quickly add a DWG with multiple layers?

Tags: qgis, dwg

In QGIS 2.14 "Essen", I need to add a DWG with multiple layers.

So I choose "[add vector layer](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/load-multiple-layers-in-qgis.html)" feature in QGIS 2.0 to import the .dwg/.dxf file.

However, QGIS adds all layers from the DWG file into one layer in QGIS. 
How to import the DWG so each layer will be in a separate QGIS-layer; 
That is, each layer in QGIS should be named the same as layer is called in the DWG file.

Comment: IMHO  QGIS 2.14 "Essen" can not import DWG.but only DXF. For DWG you must take > 2.18.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [plugin: Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/) that can give you the ability to import DXF files and categorize it by layer. The plugin also give you the ability to convert each layer in the DXF file into a shapefile while importing. However, the plugin seems to work with DXF files only. It may not work for DWG files.